# preg_match_all does not support \n

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have small problem with preg_match_all and \n

MY reqular expression:

```
/\s*DEF\s+FUNC\s+(\w+\d*)\((\w*[,\s\w]*|)\)\s*{\s*(.*)\s*};/
```

it works for text:

```
DEF FUNC test() 
{
    test1
};
```

but this doesnt work for text:

```
DEF FUNC test() 
{
    test1
    test1
};
```

I'm fighting with this 3 hours ;/
Can somebody help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to this: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

you have to use the `s` (PCRE_DOTALL) flag

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard `.` doesn't match newlines by default.

If you want it to, you have to add the flag `s` (PCRE_DOTALL):

```
preg_match_all($regex, $in, $out, PCRE_DOTALL)
```

Comment: Looks like you missed a param, `$flags` is the fourth param. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php